# Amazon GetMatchingProductForId API not returning product information

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS API `GetMatchingProductForId` is expected to return a list of "AttributeSets" for the product-id matching the input
However, we are receiving null value for "ItemAttributes".
I am calling the API as mentioned below -

1. Create an instance of MarketplaceWebServiceProducts class. This class is provided under "com.amazonservices.mws.products" package by AWS in "mws-products-1.0.jar"
2. Create an instance of Request 'GetMatchingProductForIdRequest ' and set the required parameters for it, as below -

   GetMatchingProductForIdRequest request = new GetMatchingProductForIdRequest();
   request.setSellerId(merchantId);
   request.setIdType("ASIN");
   request.setMarketplaceId(marketPlaceId);
   IdListType idListType = new IdListType();
   idListType.setId(idList);
   request.setIdList(idListType);

3.Calling the API using the above created request as below -

```
response = marketplaceWebServiceProducts.getMatchingProductForId(productRequest);
```

1. Received response, HTTP status code is 200 (Success). but getting AttributeSets as null

I am also tested this by setting a hard-coded product ID (ASIN : B007VCRRNS) found from Amazon website.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Amazon:
Thank you for contacting MWS Support. I have checked with our internal team about this and found that we are no longer exposing Feature data in API. We are just returning it as blank to avoid breaking any existing integration.

Answer (score -1):

```
$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Products/2011-10-01";

$config = array (
    'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
    'ProxyHost' => null,
    'ProxyPort' => -1,
    'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);

$service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_VERSION,
    $config
);

$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductForIdRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setMarketplaceId("A1F83G8C2ARO7P");
$request->setIdType("ASIN");
$idlist = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_IdListType();
$idlist->setId("B00BNBA6CC");
$request->SetIdList($idlist);

$response = $service->GetMatchingProductForId($request);
```